# Problem in fetching data for the Reactjs WebApp from the cache with Firebase 10.5.0 as the database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, caching

initfirebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { 
  getFirestore,
  persistentLocalCache,
  persistentMultipleTabManager,
  CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: 
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
};

const initapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, { 
  localCache: persistentLocalCache({tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager()}), cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED
});


export const auth = getAuth(initapp);
export const db = getFirestore(initapp);
export const storage = getStorage(initapp);
```

Itemlist.js

```
import React, { useEffect }  from 'react'
import { db } from "../../firebase/initfirebase";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  query,
  doc,
  setDoc,
  where,
  getDocsFromCache,
  getDocsFromServer,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Itemlist() {
  const brandname = ["Apple", "Sony", "Lenovo", "Dell", "HP", "Samsung", "Medion", "Asus"];
  useEffect(() => {
      const readdb = async () => {
        const q = query(
          collection(db, "items"),
          where('brand', 'in', brandname),
        );

        try {
          const querySnapshot = await getDocsFromCache(q);
          console.log(querySnapshot)
          if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            try {
              const querySnapshot = await getDocsFromServer(q);
              console.log(querySnapshot)
            } catch (e) {
              console.log (e)
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          //error handling
          console.log(e);
        }
      };
      readdb();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  return(
    <div> Testing </div>
  )
}
```

Firebase 10.5.0 is using and the collection has 308 documents. From the log, it showed that no data can be loaded from the cache and the data is fetched from the server. It has the same result even it is reloaded.

Should it be the data fetched from the server for the first time and then the data can be loaded from the cache later?

Comment: What do you mean by "reloaded" ?

Comment: Thanks for replying my questions. I tried to unmount this component and mounted another component and then unmounted that components and mounted again this component. I tried to refresh the page as well. 

I am not sure my understanding is very correct as I am a new learner. If the data is fetched from the server, it will saved a copy in the cache. When the component is mounted or refresh the page, that copy is still in the cache memory. Right?